# How to disable auto-refresh when running project using dotnet watch run

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I have and ASP.NET Core Web API project. I run it using:

```
dotnet watch --project WebApi.csproj run
```

I want the project to automatically rebuild, when there are changes in the code, but I don't want to reload the browser (e.g the swagger UI, which looses authorization on reload).

How do I disable auto refresh / auto reload?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dotnet-watch-configuration):

> `DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_BROWSER_REFRESH`   `dotnet watch run` attempts to refresh browsers when it detects file changes. If set to "1" or "true", this behavior is suppressed. This behavior is also suppressed if `DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_LAUNCH_BROWSER` is set.

So you can set this environment variable in various ways, one is to do it on the command line:

```
set DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_BROWSER_REFRESH=1
dotnet watch --project WebApi.csproj run
```